# JSON-taglib how to assign null value?

Tags: java, json, jsp, jstl, taglib

I want to generate null value from using json-taglib

```
<%@taglib prefix="json" uri="http://www.atg.com/taglibs/json" %>
<json:object>
    <json:property name="myString">${null}</json:property>
</json:object>
```

however, result from above code generates:

```
{
    "myString": ""
}
```

what i actually want is:

```
{
    "myString": null
}
```

Could someone please help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning value suing value parameter `<json:property name="myString" value="${null}" />`

Comment: thanks for help, but result is the same. {"myString": ""}